# Boost tokenizer re-assignment

Tags: c++, boost

I have to read multiple strings from a struct and then tokenize them using **boost tokenizer**. Basically what I have currently is this:

```
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > Tokenizer;
boost::char_separator<char> sep(";");

Tokenizer tok1(str1, sep);
...

Tokenizer tok2(str2, sep);
...

Tokenizer tok3(str3, sep);
.....
```

Note that I am creating a new tokenizer object every time. Is it possible to do this using just one tokenizer object? Something like this:

```
Tokenizer tok(str1, sep);
...

// tok(str2, sep); or tok = Tokenizer(str2, sep)
```

PS: I tried both of the above and they failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `assign` member function to assign a new token source.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<string>

void test(boost::tokenizer<>& tok)
{
    for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
        std::cout << *beg << " : ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "This is,  a test";
    boost::tokenizer<> tok(s);

    test(tok);

    tok.assign(s);
    test(tok);

    tok.assign(s);
    test(tok);
}
```

expected output:

```
This : is : a : test : 
This : is : a : test : 
This : is : a : test :
```